# Grid item not aligning as expected

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to get the content of `item` to be in the middle column, but it does not seem to be moving.

```css
.home-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 0.10fr 0.98fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.home-header {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
}

.home-main {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background: #81d4fa;
}

.item {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
}

.home-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 5 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
  div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="home-grid-container">
  <div class="home-header">
    <h1>
      <img src="/src/imgs/sitelogo.png" />
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="home-main">
    <div class="item">
      Simple, Fast, Powerful
      <input type="button" value="100% Free" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-footer">
    <div>All Rights Reserved</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: `.item` is a child of `.home-main` which is not a grid, only a child of your grid, so the grid-x rules cannot be applied

Comment: I see that. They also seem to gotten rid of the sub-grid tag. So I guess my choices are to make more grid lines or use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

The elements you want to center are descendants, but not children, of the grid container.

Because grid layout only extends between parent and child elements, the `.item` element is out of scope and will not accept grid properties.

But these elements are inline-level children of a block container, which means that `text-align: center` will work.

```css
.home-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 0.10fr 0.98fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.home-header {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
}

.home-main {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background: #81d4fa;
}

.item {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  text-align: center;    /* NEW */
}

.home-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 5 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-grid-container">
  <div class="home-header">
    <h1>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="home-main">
    <div class="item">
      Simple, Fast, Powerful
      <input type="button" value="100% Free" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-footer">
    <div>All Rights Reserved</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/odss6jvL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the grid for a child of your container, you can always just inherit the same properties.

```css
.home-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 0.10fr 0.98fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.home-header {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
}

.home-main {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background: #81d4fa;
  
  /* inherit the container-grid setup */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: inherit;
  grid-template-rows: inherit;
}

.item {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
}

.home-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 5 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
  div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="home-grid-container">
  <div class="home-header">
    <h1>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x50/cccccc/ffffff.png" />
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="home-main">
    <div class="item">
      Simple, Fast, Powerful
      <input type="button" value="100% Free" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-footer">
    <div>All Rights Reserved</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, since the item element isn't a direct child of the grid container - you can't apply grid properties to it.

Obviously, to fix this you could pull the item out of the home-main div and make it a direct child of the grid - but I'm guessing that that's not a viable solution here :)

Grid Layout Module Level 2 - [Subgrids](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/#subgrids) are supposed to solve this problem.

Subgrid is currently only a draft spec, but fwiw, in your case you would do something like:

```
.home-main {
  display: subgrid;
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

**Nevertheless**, there actually is a way to pull this off:

### **[display: contents](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-contents)** ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents))

From [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents):

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they
>   were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element
>   itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored
>   when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

So in order for the grid placement properties to work on the item, you could simply add `display: contents;` to home-main (currently working in **Firefox**)

(NB: This will obviously render the grid properties on home-main useless - but then again - they aren't necessary to place the item)

```
.home-main {
  display: contents;
  ...
}
```

```css
.home-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 0.10fr 0.98fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.home-header {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
}

.home-main {
  /*grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3; */
  display: contents;
  background: #81d4fa;
}

.item {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background: salmon;
}

.home-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 5 / span 1;
  background: #3f51b5;
}

.home-footer div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2vh;
  }
```

```html
<div class="home-grid-container">
  <div class="home-header">
    <h1>
      <img src="/src/imgs/sitelogo.png" />
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="home-main">
    <div class="item">
      Simple, Fast, Powerful
      <input type="button" value="100% Free" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-footer">
    <div>All Rights Reserved</div>
  </div>
</div>
```